# How to use class attributes in method decorators in Python?

Tags: python, logging, python-decorators, python-class

I have a decorator responsible for logging. E.g. something like this:

```
import logging
import functools
from typing import Callable


def log_container(func: Callable, logger=None):
    if logger is None:
        logger = logging.getLogger("default")
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        logger.info(f"{func.__qualname__} started.")
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        logger.info(f"{func.__qualname__} ended.")
        return result

    return wrapper
```

I have a class that has a distinct logger as an attribute, and I want to give that logger as a decorator argument. Is this possible? and if so, how?

```
class Dummy:
    logger = logging.getLogger("Dummy")
    
    @log_container(logger=Dummy.logger)
    def do_something(self):
        pass
```

Comment: did you try self.logger? Class attributes can be found on instances.

Comment: @Yuri self does not work when I'm using it in the method decoration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your decorator, as its currently defined, wouldn't work. You can't pass in the decorated function together with an argument since the decorator itself only accepts one argument: the `func` itself. If you want your decorator to accept an argument, you'll need to nest the decorator one level deeper. Which now becomes a function that returns a decorator:

```
def log_container(logger=None):
    if logger is None:
        logger = logging.getLogger("default")

    def inner(func: Callable):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            logger.info(f"{func.__qualname__} started.")
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            logger.info(f"{func.__qualname__} ended.")
            return result

        return wrapper
    return inner
```

Then when decorating the method for the `Dummy` class, don't use `Dummy.logger` since `Dummy` won't be defined until the end of the class definition, instead, you can access the class attribute `logger` directly.

```
class Dummy:
    logger = logging.getLogger("Dummy")
    
    @log_container(logger=logger)
    def do_something(self):
        pass

    # Use default logger
    @log_container()
    def do_something_else(self):
        pass
```